# WP7 XNA ContentLoadException only for specifc types of models

Tags: windows-phone-7, 3d, xna

Recently, I ported over a desktop XNA application to WP7. However, I get ContentLoadExceptions when trying to load specific types of models.

I get the following error:

```
Cannot find type Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Graphics.NodeContent, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842cf8be1de50553.
```

It attempts to load a class which is only available on the desktop version of XNA even when I use the default content pipeline. I have several types of models: terrain, buildings, and a couple other types. Building tiles refuse to load because of this error. I've tried several file formats (Collada, FBX, X, and OBJ and always get the same error).

Anyone have ideas as to why this might happen?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with assembly references. You can provide more detail?

Comment: Yep, seems that these models are either not supported or content processor or importer cannot be loaded (assembly not found, typename incorrect etc.)